# MediaPicker SelectPhotoAsync fails for Android Nougat 7.1 API 25 and greater

Tags: android, xamarin.android

The code below has been working for all Android OS versions prior to Nougat 7.1 API 25.

This method is called and it never returns just hangs when the device is Nougat 7.1 API 25.  So, Line #1 works fine and I am able to pick an image from the Photo library but Line #2 never gets called.  This exact same code with a different emulator running Nougat 7.0 or prior works fine.  I have upgrade to VS 2017 and the latest versions of Xamarian.

Any advice or guidance is appreciated.

```
var mediaFile = await this._mediaPicker.SelectPhotoAsync(new CameraMediaStorageOptions
                {
                    DefaultCamera = CameraDevice.Front,
                    MaxPixelDimension = 400
                });


_imageSource = ImageSource.FromStream(() => mediaFile.Source);
```

Comment: I tested your code on Emulator with android version 7.1, can't reproduce your issue, what's the version of your Xlabs?

Comment: Found the same issue reported here

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/63559/selectphotoasync-doesnt-work-because-of-fixuri-method-in-mediapickeractivity-cs-xlabs-camera

Comment: I am using XLabs v2.0.5782.12262.  I have upgraded to VS 2017 and have all of the latest versions of Xamarian installed.  I found this article that reports the same issue that I am having.

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/63559/selectphotoasync-doesnt-work-because-of-fixuri-method-in-mediapickeractivity-cs-xlabs-camera

Comment: Not sure what's wrong within the package, you could try to report an issue on Github. If just focus on fixing the problem of select a photo from gallery and show it in `Image` control, do you mind to use `DependecyService` to implement android native method?

Comment: OK thanks.  Yes, I have implemented the DependecyService for picture capture ONLY after HOURS of research and pulling my hair out!!  Xamarian XLabs is becoming a hindrance in a lot of ways to developer productivity.